# Azure Container Apps Dapr Output binding support for large files

Tags: azure, docker, dapr, azure-container-apps

I want to download large files (>300MB) from an Azure Blob Storage within an Azure Container App using the dapr output binding. This works without any issues for small file (~<100 MB) but it keeps failing for files that are larger than 300 MB.

My Container has 4GiB RAM and 2 CPU and regarding the Metrics Dashboard, I am way under the resource limits. I can reproduce the error when connecting to the container using a bash and try to retrieve the files using the dapr HTTP API with the following command:

```
curl -L -d '{ "operation": "get", "metadata": { "blobName": "XY_2217.ziprt" }}' http://localhost:3500/v1.0/bindings/raw-data-storage --output testlarge.zip
```

Here is a screenshot that shows two downloads. The first with a small file is working, the second with a large file keeps failing:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any logs associate with the application?

Comment: @tmarwen Within the application we receive a "StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE" and a "Socket closed" message. But as mentioned, we are also not able to download the file using the plain DAPR API

Comment: This is likely to highlight a `dapr` runtime bug. You might need to report it on the project issues section.